# Probability of success of at least one event

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Given a set of n independent events $A_1, A_2, A_3,......A_n$ with their respective probabilities $p_1, p_2, p_3,......p_n$, the task is to find the probability of success of at least one event from the given set of events.

Here is my solution:

P(failure of ith event) $= P\left(A_i^c\right)$

$\Rightarrow P\left(A_i^c\right)= p_i^c = 1 - p_i \forall i\in[1,n]$

So, P(failure of all events) $= P(\forall i \in[1,n], A_i^c)$

$$\Rightarrow P(\forall i \in[1,n], A_i^c) = P\left(\cap_{i=0}^n A_i^c\right)$$

Since the events are independent-

$$\Rightarrow P(\forall i \in[1,n], A_i^c) = \Pi_{i=1}^np_i^c = \Pi_{i=1}^n\left(1-p_i\right)$$

Now $$\sim(\forall i \in[1,n], A_i^c) = \exists i \in \left[1, n\right],A_i$$
The predicate $\exists i \in \left[1, n\right],A_i$ means that there is at least one value of $i$ for which $A_i$ holds true which is what we have to find.

Again,$$\sim\left(P(\forall i \in[1,n], A_i^c)\right) = 1 - P(\forall i \in[1,n], A_i^c)$$

$$\Rightarrow P\left(\exists i \in \left[1, n\right],A_i\right) = 1 - P(\forall i \in[1,n], A_i^c)$$

$$\Rightarrow P\left(\exists i \in \left[1, n\right],A_i\right) = 1 - \Pi_{i=1}^n\left(1-p_i\right),$$which is the required result.

However, when I test this for a simple coin toss, the result is wrong.
For example, the probability of getting at least a head or a tail, i.e, the probability of getting a head or a tail should be one but it comes out to be 3/4 which is wrong.
Exactly what have I done wrong in the above derivation?

Comment: What are the events $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n$ in your coin toss example ?

Comment: In your "simple coin toss", note that the event of getting a head and the event of getting a tail are not independent (They are very dependent. In fact, we get a head IFF we don't get a tail). So your work/result doesn't apply.

Comment: I see. You're right getting a heads or a tails are not independent events. If I use 2 coins though and calculate the probability of getting at least one heads, then the answer comes out to be 3/4 which is correct. Thanks for explaining